# .Net RIA Services and SubSonic3 usage examples

Tags: subsonic3, wcf-ria-services

I am looking for any examples which ideally cover several possible combinations ( SimpleRepository, ActiveRecord , POCO ) - something similar to Brad Abrams

http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2009/10/27/index-for-business-apps-example-for-silverlight-3-rtm-and-net-ria-services-july-update.aspx

but ORM  is SubSonic.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am looking for the same thing.